# Codes for modifying/updating Azure VM Tags value doesn't work in Azure PowerShell Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I'm working on updating/modifying Azure VM Tags value, the code works successfully when I tested it on my local PowerShell ISE and connected to our Azure subscription (It successfully modify the existing Tag value) but when I tested it in our Azure PowerShell Runbooks in Azure Portal. The code doesn't work that is supposed to be, instead it deletes all the existing Tags.

Here's the sample code which I searched from this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e8cbcdc-98ba-4402-90fc-f285a33a42c6/how-to-update-tag-values?forum=azureautomation):

```
#Get all tags from Resource (VM)
$GetVM = Get-AzureRMVM -Name 'myVM' -ResourceGroupName 'myrg'
$tags = (Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceName $GetVM.Name -ResourceGroupName $GetVM.ResourceGroupName).Tags

#Modifying the value of the Tag
$tags['tag1'] = "value1"

#Updating the Tags
$UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags -ResourceName $GetVM.Name -ResourceGroupName $GetVM.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -Force
```

Comment: try updating azure powershell modules to latest verson in Azure Automation, although the code looks okay.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the rights to update modules, are there any other workarounds? Currently the AzureRM version are on 1.0.*.

Comment: 1.0.*? thats like 4 years ago or something ;) no, you'd have to update them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, as the comment from @4c74356b41, you should update your module. After I update the module `AzureRM.Compute`, `AzureRM.Profile`, `AzureRM.Resources` directly from Shared Resources-Modules---Browse Gallery---search each module like AzureRM.Compute--click **Import**. After update these modules, this runbook works.

[image]

[image]